# Should I include a plain JS interface for Typescript-based NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm creating an open source library intended for distribution as an NPM package. I'll write it in Typescript. I'm aware that not all potential users of my library will use Typescript. So I'd like to be friendly to the plain JS coders out there. And people use different build environments, which could add other wrinkles I can't predict right now.

Should I include an API facade that exports plain JS wrappers to my Typescript functions? If that seems wrong, maybe you could explain what a "friendly" approach would be for varied users of my package. Maybe nothing is needed at all.

At a technical level, I can work through individual import/export scenarios. This is more a question about what works well in the field with developer configurations I might not be able to predict.

Comment: TS gets compiled to JS at the end anyway. You usualy compile your ts to js first, and then publish the compiled version

Comment: You can just write plain js without TS in your source code and create *.d.ts files.  See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)

Comment: Re: "You can just write plain js"
Thanks, but I want my package's source code to be written in Typescript, though. Maybe I misunderstand your point.